# Python tax calculator - algorithm is not working correctly

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm

I'm very new to python so I apologize if this question is simple. I am trying to write an algorithm that calculates the difference in rates between 2017 and 2018 based on a user-inputted salary. I've gotten to the point where the algorithm does calculate a tax rate, however it seems to do it backwards, i.e. the lower the inputted income, the higher the tax owed, something that the government, for all its flaws, generally doesn't do. I've tried different things for the algorithm but I'm still not sure where I'm going wrong. Any ideas or advice would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

```
# of tax brackets
levels = 6
#2017 tax rates
rates2017 = [0, 10, 15, 25, 28, 33, 35]
#2018 tax rates
rates2018 = []
#2017 income tax thresholds
incomes2017 = [0, 9325, 37950, 91900, 191650, 416700, 418400]

# take in a value for net income and assign it to int
netincome = int(input('Please input an integer for income: '))

#initialize the variables used
tax_owed = 0
taxable_income = 0
netincomeleft = netincome - 6500
i = levels

#while loop calculates the income tax
while i >= 0:
    taxable_income = netincomeleft - incomes2017[i]
    tax_owed += taxable_income * (rates2017[i]/100)
    netincomeleft = incomes2017[i]
    i -= 1

#multiply tax owed by -1 to get a positive int for clarity
taxes_owed = tax_owed * -1

# print out the 2017 tax owed
print('tax owed on $', netincome, 'after standard deduction is ', taxes_owed)
```

*for the sake of clarity, I'm using Python 3 in a Jupyter notebook environment

Comment: `tax owed on $ 5 after standard deduction is  49245.75` #looksGoodToMe

Comment: The general debugging steps are to go line by line and print out what you expect the answer to be. If I were you I would put a print statement in your while loop and print out all the variables involved and then compared to what you would expect with pen and paper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: I did figure this out eventually. Turns out the government does not collect more tax than income, except for special people. Thanks everyone for your help!

```
levels = 6
rates2017 = [0, 10, 15, 25, 28, 33, 35]
rates2018 = []
incomes2017 = [0, 9325, 37950, 91900, 191650, 416700, 418400]

netincome = int(input('Please input an integer for income: '))
tax_owed = 0
taxable_income = 0
standard_deduction = 6500

netincomeleft = netincome - standard_deduction
i = 0

while levels >= 0 and taxable_income >=0 and netincomeleft >= 0:
    if (netincomeleft - incomes2017[i]) < 0:
        taxable_income = netincome - incomes2017[i-1] - standard_deduction
    else: 
        taxable_income = netincomeleft - incomes2017[i]
    tax_owed += (taxable_income * (rates2017[i]/100))
    netincomeleft = netincomeleft - incomes2017[i]
    i += 1
    levels -= 1

taxes_owed = tax_owed
print('tax owed on $', netincome, 'after standard deduction is ', taxes_owed)
```

Answer (score 2):

You are working mostly with negative numbers....you don't check whether their income EXCEEDS the specific level, so with an income of 100 you charge them NEGATIVE tax rate of (418400 - 100) and so on.

You want to start your level at the first number EXCEEDING netincomeleft, and then not multiply by -1!

So for a small income "level" should start at 0 or 1, not at 6.

Answer (score 0):

```
def USA():
    tax=0
    if salary<=9700:
        tax=9700*0.1
    elif salary<=39475:
        tax=970+(salary-9700)*0.12
    elif salary<=84200:
        tax=4543+(salary-39475)*0.22 
    elif salary<=160725:
        tax=14382.5+(salary-84200)*0.24
    elif salary<=204100:
        tax=32748.5+(salary-160725)*0.32  
    elif salary<=510300:
        tax=139918.5+(salary-204100)*0.35
    else:
        tax=328729.87+(salary-510300)*0.37
    return ('tax owed on $', salary, 'after standard deduction is ', tax, 'and your netincome is ', (salary-tax) )          
salary=int(input('Please input an integer for income: '))      
print(USA())
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow and thanks for the answer. Please update (edit) your answer with the proper commentary and how it solves the problem (comment like the one you've provided should be a part of your response).